# Selecting the biggest ZIP code from a column

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the biggest ZIP code in DB. Normally I do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   Select * From tbuser ORDER BY zip DESC
) 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

with this code I can get the biggest zip code value without a duplicate row (since zip code is not a primary key).

But the main company at Japan said that I cant use it since when the connection is slow or the DB have very large data, you cant get the right row of it. It will be a great help for me if someone can helps.

Comment: This sounds like a false limitation, frankly. But what Oracle version are you using?

Comment: The slow connection will have no impact on this. Oracle will only transmit a single row back to the program running the statement. You either understood something wrong (regarding the slow connection part) or whoever said that doesn't know how Oracle processes a query.

Comment: Ah it's the lastest ver though. I don't know why but the main company in japan said that problem and request us to use other methods.Most likely we work by connect with japan DB through internet.

Comment: If the table is really huge, why not `partition` it?

Comment: But you're not retrieving only the zip code - you're retrieving all fields from the table. If you want just the max zip code use `SELECT MAX(zip)...`.

Comment: ah I want to retrieving a row that have a biggest zip code from the table.

Comment: _"But the main company at Japan said that I cant use it since when the connection is slow or the DB have very large data,"_ Reading your various comments -- isn't the real issue _"how to retrieve large rows on unreliable connection ?"_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want to get the biggest ZIP code in DB.

If you really *only* want the zip code, try that:

```
SELECT MAX(zip) FROM TBUSER;
```

This will use the index on the `zip` column (if it exists).

That being said, Oracle is usually smart enough to properly optimize sub-query selection using `ROWNUM`. Maybe your main company is more concerned about the possible "full table" ̀ORDER BY` in the subquery ? OTH, if the issue is really with "slow network", maybe worth taking some time with your DBA to look on the wire using a network analyzer or some other tool if your approach really leads to "excessive bandwidth consumption". I sincerely doubt about that...

---

If you want to retrieve the whole row having the maximum zip code here is a slight variation on [an other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27820362/2363712) (in my opinion, this is one of the rare case for using a `NATURAL JOIN`):

```
select * from t
natural join (select max(zip) zip from t);
```

Of course, in case of duplicates, this will return multiple rows. You will have to combine that with one of the several options posted in the various other answers to return only 1 row.

As an extra solution, and since you are not allowed to use `ROWNUM` (and assuming `row_number` is arbitrary forbidden too), you can achieve the desired result using something as contrived as:

```
select * from t
where rowid = (
  select min(t.rowid) rid from t
  natural join (select max(zip) zip from t)
);
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bd63/5

But honestly, there isn't any serious reason to hope that such query will perform better than the simple `... ORDER BY something DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1` query.

Comment: thanks you for your answer Sylvain Leroux.
But the main problem with the SELECT Max is if I have two biggest zip code like "99800" it will show both row at the same time too.

Comment: @Nguyen _" if I have two biggest zip code like "99800" it will show both row at the same time too"_ -- No it won't: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fe5d9/2

Comment: @SylvainLeroux ugh I don't know why but it show two like

{usera homie 99800 streets9999 
userb josep 99800 streets3453}

I would like to provide you a screen shot but I cant access in my home.

Comment: What do you want as result exactly? A ( random ) result of one row out of the rows with the max zip or the max zip?

Comment: A exactly one row with the max zip, if it have more rows with the same max zip then it only show the first row of these max zip.And cant use rownum to do it.

Comment: They ask me to write a small function to do that though. So no partition for now.

Comment: @NguyenTrongNhan _"with the same max zip then it only show the first row of these max zip"_ Please note "the first" is rather meaningless here as, without any additional ordering (either on some other column, or on generated values like `ROWNUM`), you will have to consider all rows having the "max" zip code as an unordered set. You can obtain "one arbitrary row" having the maximum zip code. But not the "first one".

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux Thanks you very much. It look like they accept the natural join function.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds to me like bad advice (masquerading as a rule) from a newbie data base administrator who doesn't understand what he's looking at.  That insight isn't going to help you, though. Rarely does a conversation starting with "you're an obstructionist incompetent" achieve anything.

So, here's the thing. First of all, you need to make sure there's an *index* on your `zip` column. It doesn't have to be a primary key.

Second, you can try explaining that Oracle's table servers do, in fact, optimize the `... ORDER BY something DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1` style of query. Their servers do a good job of that. Your use case is very common.

But if that doesn't work on your DBA, try saying "I heard you" and do this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT a.* 
      FROM ( SELECT MAX(zip) zip FROM zip ) b
      JOIN ZIP a ON (a.zip = b.zip)
 ) WHERE rownum <= 1
```

This will get one row with the highest numbered `zip` value without the `ORDER BY` that your DBA mistakenly believes is messing up his server's RAM pool.  And, it's reasonably efficient. As long as `zip` has an index.

Comment: Thanks you @Ollie Jones, I will try it tomorrow.
 ugh They requested not to use rownum....

Answer (score 3):

As you are looking for a way to get the desired record without rownum now, ...

... here is how to do it from Oracle 12c onward:

```
select * 
from tbuser
order by zip desc fetch first 1 row only;
```

... and here is how to do it before Oracle 12c:

```
select * 
from (select tbuser.*, row_number() over(order by zip desc) as rn from tbuser)
where rn = 1;
```

EDIT: As Sylvain Leroux pointed out, it is more work for the dbms to sort all records rather than just find the maximum. Here is a max query without rownum:

```
select * 
from tbuser where rowid =
(select max(rowid) keep (dense_rank last order by zip) from tbuser);
```

But as Sylvain Leroux also mentioned, it makes also a difference whether there is an index on the column. Some tests I did show that with an index on the column, the analytic functions are slower than the traditional functions. Your original query would just get into the index, go to the highest value, pick the record and then stop. You won't get this any faster. My last mentioned query being quite fast on a none-indexed column is slower than yours on an indexed column.

Comment: @PIyush Ah I see, sorry

Comment: Do you know if Oracle will optimize such query properly ? I have the (totally unfounded) feeling that the `rownum` version would perform better -- despite what's the OP's DBA is claiming...

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux: The dbms will have to sort all records and then pick the first. This is the same with rownum, row_number and fetch first. There won't be much to do for the optimizer hence.

Comment: @Thorsten _"The dbms will have to *sort* all records"_ As a matter of fact, I was wondering if Oracle was able to understand that a _full sort_ isn't necessary here. It only have to _find the maximum_. Or course, with a proper index on the `zip` column, no sort is required since the values are already ordered in the index.

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux: Oops, you are right of course, I was short-sighted. Finding just the maximum and getting that record then is of course faster than sorting all records. I'll add another option and appropriate remarks to my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements seem arbitrary, but this should give you the result you've requested.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbuser 
      WHERE zip = (SELECT MAX(zip) FROM tbuser)) 
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: I don't believe your original result can be reproduced without rownum. If an arbitrary user and address are not important, you could do something like SELECT 'genericId', 'genericUser', MAX(zip), 'genericAddress' FROM tbuser

Comment: Why scan the table twice? It is not efficient. In `Oracle 12c`, you could use `fetch first 1 rows only` with `order by desc`.

Answer (score 2):

OK - try something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TBUSER
  WHERE ZIP = (SELECT MAX(ZIP) FROM TBUSER);
```

Fetch a single row from a cursor based on the above statement, then close the cursor. If you're using PL/SQL you could do it like this:

```
FOR aRow IN (SELECT *
               FROM TBUSER
               WHERE ZIP = (SELECT MAX(ZIP) FROM TBUSER))
LOOP
   -- Do something with aRow

   -- then force an exit from the loop

   EXIT;
END LOOP;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering that nobody posted this answer yet. I think that is the way, you should do something like that.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   Select a.*, max(zip) over () max_zip
   From tbuser a
) 
WHERE zip=max_zip
and rownum = 1
```

Comment: Ah thanks you, but they dont allow to use rownum though.

Comment: @Nguyen Trong Nhan: This query does the same thing as yours anyhow. But why do they forbid certain ways to query?

Comment: umm they only give me a explain that with large DB ( because these DB store jp population in each ward, so sometime with the code I post in 1st post, it give a wrong result. They want to use another way without rownum but have exact the same time execute as rownum.

Answer (score 1):

Your query gets exactly one random row of all records having the max zip code. So it cannot be the problem that you retrieve a record with another zip code or more than one record or zero records (as long as there is at least one record in the table).

Maybe Japan simply expects one of the other rows with that zip code? Then you may just have to add another order criteria to get that particular desired row.

Another thought: As they are talking about slow connection speed, it may also be that they enter a new max zip code on one session, query with another and get the old max zip, because the insert statement of the other session hasn't gone through yet. But well, that's just the way this works of course.

BTW: A strange thing to select a maximum zip code. I guess that's just an example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Ya, because Vietnam internet is pretty bad at the moment. They want us to find a new way to get full data in a row from the biggest column in the table. Because of the bad connection, it's very hard to execute a SQL code in DB since we need to connect to jp DB first.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are getting multiple records using MAX function (which is not possible, but in your case you are getting, I don't know how until you post screenshot) then You can use DISTINCT in your sql query to get single record

```
SELECT DISTINCT MAX(zipcode) FROM TableUSER
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50e57/5)

Comment: He's getting multiple records, because he isn't selecting the zipcode field he's selecting entire rows.

Comment: @FrumRoll: No. The query Nguyen Trong Nhan posted selects one record only or the dbms has a severe bug.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner My response was in reference to Piyush's statement that Nguyen Trong Nhan stated he is receiving multiple records when using the MAX function. You are correct that Nguyen Trong Nhan's original query retrieves a single record.